# How to force a redifinition in c++

Tags: c++, macos

I am in a weird predicament where i have no control of libraries that am using. To explain further, I am using two libraries liba and libb. Libb needs liba to function. Now here comes the problem, liba not only contain the class but it also defines it and libb looks for that definition. Its all good when everything works but when its not, im out of luck.

liba.h

```
class myclassA{
 // some code here
};

myclassA varA(0,2,1,3);  //The parameters need to be changed
```

Of course i can edit liba.h locally, but that would mean if my code were to be compiled with another compute the modification would not persist and would have to edit its liba.h, every single time for every computer.

So is there some way to force redifine varA without throwing an error at compilation?

mycode looks like this:

```
#include <liba.h>
myvlassA varA(0,1,2,3); // Of course this throws a multiple definition error
#include <libb.h>
```

Is there a way around of basically deleting the old variable difinition with my new one?

Comment: Derive from `myclassA` and use the derived class wherever you need to?

Comment: The library is defining global variables in the header? That library has much bigger problems. If you include it in two different C++ source files, your linker will likely choke. Those globals should be in the C/C++ source code backing the headers.

Comment: Is this some "header-only" library? Usually, those have a macro that you define prior to including its header where you can tell it to only act as a header or as an implementation. Take a look at that lib and see if it provides that. If yes, then you would use that to turn off the global definitions of that lib and turn them on only in one of your `cpp` files, which would then act as the single definition of whatever that lib defines.

Comment: `#define varA` ...?

Comment: @CoryKramer it is defined like this `something::myClassA varA(0, 2, 1, 3);` I do not know how to reassign, can you teach me so i can try it out?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it is how it is thats why i said, its all good when it works :D

Comment: have you tried `varA = something::myClassA(1,2,3,4);`?

Comment: @NikosC. there is actually a macro `#if howmany>0` but its a rat nest of files that im affraid that if i declare the howmany to some number i might affect some other part of the library. (if i cant find another solution i will be forced to check all these files see how the howmany variable is used)

Comment: @YSC im getting an error saying varA does not name a type

Comment: Doesn't make sense

Comment: @YSC i had the same thought, i just double checked and the declaration is actually in the liba.cpp not in the liba.h .

Comment: It changes everything. You should [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <liba.h>

myclassA myVarA(0,1,2,3);

#define varA myVarA
#include <libb.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

At one point I had to do something similar maybe you want something like

```
    #include <stdio.h>
/* gcc lmao.c -Wl,--wrap=puts -o lmao */
int __real_puts(const char*);
int __wrap_puts(const char*a) {
    __real_puts("u just got hacked\n");
    __real_puts(a);
}
int main() {
    /* gcc uses puts for this cool right*/
    printf("main, calling thing\n");
}
```

this will print

```
u just got hacked
main, calling thing
```